# iOS: Change state of textfield userInteractionEnabled depending on edit or non edit mode

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextfield

In a table view cell I want to make a textfield's userInteractionEnabled property YES in edit mode and NO in non edit mode (so that the whole cell is "clickable" and firing the segue).

So I've changed my code to this (of the table view cell):

```
- (void) setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated{
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
    if (editing){
        self.title.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    }  else if (!editing){
        self.title.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    }
}
```

If I do this and end the edit mode, my keyboard is correctly hidden and all textfields change to non edit mode. However if I change back to edit mode my last active textfield is "remembered" and the keyboard is automatically shown, since the keyboard cursor is already in this last textfield.

Without this enabling and disabling action (and always have it enabled), it works fine and no textfield is selected when edit mode is started. What am I missing here? What do I need to change?

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `resignFirstResponder` on the text field when you disable it.

You may also want to switch between using a text field for editing and a label for display only so that they are visually different and not confusing to users ("why can't I tap to edit at the moment?").

Comment: Visually they are different. I left out some code, I'm removing the border and white background while in non edit state. But I've tried this resignFirstResponder, didn't really work...I mean they all do resign the first responder if I don't change this behaviour which the userInteractionsEnabled...